# How to uninstall a software from command line silently without user intervention?

Tags: windows, installation, installshield, uninstallation

I have installed Btrieve 12 from command line silently using the "/qn" option provided by the Btrieve vendor.
I have to uninstall the same program from command line silently.
How to do that?
Can any windows program be uninstalled from command line silently without user intervention? or this support has to be given by the software vendor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command

```
msiexec /x [Installer path] /q /L*VX [LogFilePath]
```